# Fazer uma regex para remover caracteres

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, regex

Num retorno de uma função jquery, a data retornada vem nesse formato.

```
/Date(1401731794773)/
```

Gostaria de remover os caracteres inválidos nessa data, que são:

`/Date(` e `)/`

Preciso apenas do componente data(numérico restante) para compor uma data válida. Por isso como eu faço isso? Acho que uma REGEX seria o melhor caminho, certo?

Answer (score 6):

Regex nesse caso é *overkill*... Use simplesmente `substring`:

```
var entrada = "/Date(1401731794773)/";
var conteudo = entrada.substring(6, entrada.length-2);
```

Isso é possível nesse caso pois tanto o prefixo quanto o sufixo têm tamanho fixo: `"/Date(".length == 6` e `")/".length == 2`.

**Nota:** minha resposta original assumiu que o codigo estava no lado servidor, em C#. De todo modo, a solução seria a mesma:

```
string entrada = "/Date(1401731794773)/";
string conteudo = entrada.Substring(6, entrada.length-2);
```

Comment: esta segunda solução funciona tanto para Javascript quanto C# - a única diferença é que em C# o S deve ser maiúsculo em Substring

Comment: @Igomide Verdade, esse detalhe me passou despercebido. Corrigi, e mudei também a ordem pra solução em JavaScript vir primeiro (mantive o `string` explícito entretanto). Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Com expressões regulares pode-se fazer assim:

```
var resultado = "/Date(1401731794773)/"

data = resultado.match(/[\d]+/);
console.log(data); // 1401731794773
```

A expressão [`/[\d]+/`](http://regex101.com/r/lA0bF7) vai fazer que somente seja capturado números.

Também é possível estar fazendo desse modo:

```
var resultado = "/Date(1401731794773)/"

data = resultado.replace(/[^\d]+/g, "");
console.log(data); // 1401731794773
```

A expressão [`/[^\d]+/g`](http://regex101.com/r/zP4jN4) faz com que seja correspondido todos os caracteres não-numéricos, que no caso, `Date()` assim bastando fazer a troca chamando o `replace()`.

Comment: Alternativamente, pode se usar simplesmente `\d+` para capturar números (não precisa dos colchetes) e `\D+` para capturar não-números (repare no "D" em maiúsculo).

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```
var dtCadastro = data.agendamento.DataCadastro.substring(6, data.agendamento.DataCadastro.length - 2);
var dtAgendanmento = data.agendamento.DataAgendamento(6, data.agendamento.DataAgendamento.length - 2);
var dtVisita = data.agendamento.DataVisita(6, data.agendamento.DataVisita.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais eficiente em javascript é:

```
var val = "/Date(1402369200000)/";
var re = "/-?\d+/";
console.log(re.exec(val));

// output: ["1402369200000"]
```